# Probability distribution that favours spread in multiple given directions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I study mathematics, however my question is quite "broad" but I'm sure the answer will be very narrow instead!

I was looking at the normal distribution (both univariate and multivariate) and this is centred in a desired point in space and favours spread very close to the centre, while getting smaller and smaller in the tails.

Then I looked at exponential distribution and this favours spread towards one end (or quadrant, etc), while getting smaller and smaller in the other tail.

In general, although the shape of the most common distributions change, they all have "similar" characteristics, also the uniform one.

What I am looking for is a probability distribution that:

- Can be multivariate/multidimensional (for instance the normal distribution! I need many dimensions, so from 2 to 100 say).
- Can be "centred" on a point in space.
- **The spread can be "controlled" by certain parameters. But controlled in a way that we can pick some points in space (hopefully different from the centre) and make so that the spread favours those points. For instance if there is a point in the diagonal of he first quadrant, at say (100,100) and there is a point on the second quadrant diagonal, say (-100,100), then the spread of a distribution centred at the origin, would go towards the positive y axis or towards both the diagonal of the first quadrant and the diagonal of the second quadrant.**

Is there a distribution that fulfils all of the above conditions? Or a distribution that fulfils only the first and the third?

I tried looking at the Cauchy, Gamma, Beta, Uniform, Lognormal,Normal, but none of them seems to have the third property!

Comment: A multivariate normal could concentrate probability in a particular direction (both ways).  A mixture of multivariate normals could concentrate probability more than one direction.  A mixture involving other distributions could assist one way concentration

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution As what Henry said above, mixture distribution is probably your best chance to obtain a multimodal distribution.

Comment: @Henry  would you have any suggestion? Imagine the task is: given a point in space (centre) and n points in space, I want to sample points such that these are randomly sampled, but there is more probability towards the direction of each of the n points and the mother.